# Indexing datetime in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing

What is the best way to index a datetime in MySQL?  Which method is faster:

1. Store the datetime as a double (via unix timestamp)
2. Store the datetime as a datetime

The application generating the timestamp data can output either format.  Unfortunately, datetime will be a key for this particular data structure so speed will matter.

Also, is it possible to make an index on an expression?  For example, index on `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mydate)` where mydate is a field in a table and UNIX_TIMESTAMP is a mysql function.  I know that [Postgres can do it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html).  I'm thinking there must be a way in mysql as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think either method will be much faster than the other, but if you choose a 'datetime' it will be a lot easier to operate with the standard date time functions.

MySQL doesn't support [functional indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/indexes-functional.html).

Answer (score -3):

I think using an integer will be faster because `where datetime >= '2010-09-30 01:31:41'` will never hit an index.  However `where intTimestamp >= 237492347`  will.

Comment: Why would that not use an index?

Comment: It does hit an index (provided the index is there). You can *dig* into MySQL way of performing queries by using `EXPLAIN SELECT (...)`