# MySQL performance: sort is slow in large table, even though filtered subset is small

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I'm trying to performance tune my MySQL query, but am running into a problem that I don't understand (and so can't fix). Essentially, it can sort 165,000 rows faster if they are in their own table than if they are a subset of a larger table.

The table fl6 has 2 million rows. It has an index x1 on (departure_out). departure_out is a date type.

The following select finds 165,916 rows. It takes 0.1 second.

```
select count(*) 
from fl6 
where departure_out > "2013-04-01" 
and departure_out < "2013-04-05";
```

The following select has the same where clause, but sorts on price. It takes 0.5 seconds. 0.4 seconds to sort 165,000 rows.

```
select id 
from fl6 
where departure_out > "2013-04-01" 
and departure_out < "2013-04-05"
order by price_total limit 1;
```

I wanted to see if it could be faster, so, I created a small table containing just the 165,916 rows. Then I did the sort on that. It took 0.16 seconds.

```
select id 
from fl6_small
order by price_total limit 1;
```

So, it can fairly quickly sort 165,000 rows, but it takes more than twice as long if it's a subset of a larger table?? How do I get it to do that? Why the difference?

Couple of things: I already tried putting an index on (price) and (departure_out, price). That makes no difference. Anyway, it shouldn't be necessary with an index if the search in fl6_small shows how fast it can sort even without.

EDIT:

(Edited some of the row counts and times above to match the tables used for explain plan)

The explain plan:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fl6   | range | x1            | x1   | 3       | NULL | 160493 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Is there an index on price_total on your small table? If there is one mysql uses it for sorting instead of filesort.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the first case, MySQL will create a temporary table with the 165000 rows and sort them without the index. Even if there is an index on the price column, it can't be used for sorting.

Your small table might be able to use the index for sorting and therefore is much faster.

Comment: An index on (departure_out,price_total) will only help if the query has `WHERE departure_out = xxx`. It will not help for a range condition.

Comment: @Vatev Are you absolutely sure? I don't see any reason why MySQL should behave that way.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I don't think its even possible to use the index that way. The reason it works for `=` is that all the results are in a single sub-tree in the index.

Comment: Oh, now I see the mistake in my thoughts; the ordering is different than that of the index; it doesn't work, you are completely right

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXPLAIN statement to check bottlenecks of your query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html 
and also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html

Comment: Yes, I tried explain, it just says that it uses the index on departure_date.

Comment: @user984003: for which query? Both of them?

Comment: Can you post result of EXPLAIN, with full EXPLAIN query also? What is (departure_time)? Is this same as departure_out?

Comment: Regarding indexes on the datetime types, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812843/indexing-datetime-in-mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594229/mysql-integer-vs-datetime-index  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013301/mysql-datetime-index-is-not-working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568933/mysql-not-using-datetime-index-when-table-has-other-fields

Comment: oops, yes, departure_time should have read departure_out. Will fix it now.

Comment: Did that. Note that the times and row counts have changed. The original table was gone, so I redid it all with a slightly different table to get the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a couple of problems.

Nitpicky point - in the large table you are doing more than a simple sort, you are looking for records first, then sorting. On the small table you didn't search by depature_time. But it's a tiny bit of cheating, since the larger table, in order to know which n to use, it first has to build the table. If it's indexed though, it's not likely that significant as your test shows.. it still took 0.1 of the 0.5 seconds it seems. Try the where clause on the small table as well, should take slightly more time. If it doesn't then it points to:

**Second, **cache misses***:*

2,000K records may be significantly more than 150K records on the machine you're using, unless you have a dedicated box just for mysql increasing the likelihood of cache misses. These misses could be a much larger penalty than even if you have a n^2 sort or worse of records loaded in memory and memory aligned. If you run these tests on a box with a lot of ram, assuming all else is equal, there should be less discrepancy.